# Bash remove any character which is no leading space

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the trailing spaces (and eventually tabs) of a bash variable. The purpose is to insert some code in gedit using the external tools plugin at the matching indentation level.

For example if a string looks like this:

```
'        a string containing multiple spaces and other characters():'
```

I want to get the following:

```
'        '
```

The quotes are just there for readability in this post.
Is there a simple way in bash to do this?

For anyone wondering about the gedit external tool, I'm using this to insert a pdb breakpoint:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=$GEDIT_CURRENT_LINE
foo="${foo%%[^ ]*}"
echo -n "
${foo}import pdb
${foo}pdb.set_trace()"
```

Comment: You mean you want to get the leading spaces, right?

Comment: Right, but an answer has been given already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure Bash — or any POSIX shell — you can write, e.g.:

```
foo='        a string containing multiple spaces and other characters():'
foo="${foo%%[^ ]*}"
echo "<$foo>"    # prints '<        >'
```

(`${parameter%%word}` expands to the value of `parameter`, minus the longest trailing substring that matches `word`. In this case `word` is `[^ ]*`, meaning "any non-space character, followed by zero or more characters", so the longest trailing substring that matches it is the trailing substring starting at the first non-space character. For more information, see [§3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

Comment: Might suggest using `"${foo%%[^[:space:]]}"` to also handle tabs and other whitespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You're missing an asterisk, but yeah, that's a good suggestion. It depends what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\( *\).*/\1/' your.file
```

Or if you need quotes around that whitepsace to make it visible use:

```
sed "s/\( *\).*/'\1'/" your.file
```

---

Test:

```
echo '        a string containing multiple spaces and other characters():' \
    | sed "s/\( *\).*/'\1'/" your.file
```

Output:

```
'        '
```

(not much, just whitespace :), but that's what you wanted)